# React onClick not working / attempting to have my projects drop down with specific button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I am editing my portfolio so I don't have a cluster of projects when opened:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIKNa.jpg

So I added buttons for the languages and frameworks in an attempt to have them dropdown with an onClick. I added an onClick param and the function to cater to it but in the console, the console.log("this button was clicked") won't show up.

Additionally, If anyone has resources to help me achieve this drop list for my portfolio I would appreciate it here is my code and the object I am using to store my data.

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class Porfolio extends Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
  };

  render() {
    let resumeData = this.props.resumeData;
    return (
      <section id="portfolio">
        <h1>Check Out Some of My Projects!</h1>
        <div className="portfolio__button__layout">
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Javascript</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CSS & HTML</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>React</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>NodeJS</button>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Ruby on Rails</button>
        </div>
        <div className="portfolioGrid">
          {resumeData.portfolio &&
            resumeData.portfolio.map(item => {
              return (
                <a
                  href={`${item.url}`}
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  target="_blank"
                >
                  <div className="portfolio-item portfolioGridSquare">
                    <div className="item-wrap">
                      <img
                        src={`${item.imgurl}`}
                        alt="these are my projects"
                        className="item-img"
                      />
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                          <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                          <p>{item.description}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              );
            })}
          <div id="portfolio-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

AND THE OBJECT

```
  portfolio: [
    {
      name: "OmniFood",
      description:
        "CSS/HTML - Food delivery application that involves fluid grids, proper design techniques, positioning, media queries, Jquery, and much more. This project is responsive on web, tablets and iPhones of all sizes.",
      imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/hvLOGi1KsF02XiZ1DD/giphy.gif",
      url: "https://stephenbilham.github.io/SbOmniFood/"
    },
    {
      name: "Forkify",
      description:
        "JS - Here you can search through an API of recipes and add your favorites to a shopping list/favorite recipes (ingredients change with serving size). This was a complex app, using Async functions, fetch, await, callbacks, and closures",
      imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/ekeOYzzNEpW73RIcSb/giphy.gif",
      url:
        "https://github.com/stephenbilham/Financial-budgeting-App/tree/master/Budgety/Starter"
    },
    {
      name: "Connect Four",
      description:
        "React - This was logically challenging. The hardest part was finding all of the winning combinations using mathamatical algorithims/trial and error. The stetch goal is to add animation for the connect four pieces to fall.",
      imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/YrC2lEAcG4loOj2aLI/giphy.gif",
      url: ""
    },
    {
      name: "Laptop Store",
      description:
        "Node JS - Node Js practice where the purpose was to learn how to properly route based on filesharing/URL/ID's and rendering a cool looking laptop store application. This was the first introduction that I had to Node JS. ",
      imgurl: "https://media.giphy.com/media/VGKPGZX3F2fDzC3zxX/giphy.gif",
      url: ""
    },
```

Comment: in the first JS button, I used this.handleClick just to see if it would change anything. It didn't, I know it is not correct.

Comment: Define `handleClick` outside the render function in the main class body, then correctly attach it using `this.handleClick`.

Comment: It still does not work. I edited the work above so you can see the changes

Comment: Seems to be functional [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-dewdney-z53us?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FPortfolio.jsx&theme=dark).

Comment: Are you able to create a codesandbox (or similar) that accurately reproduces the issue to share here? Based upon a response comment in one of the answers it sounds like you have some CSS/style interference.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test with this code ?

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Javascript</button>
```

I think you should use an anonymous function

Comment: Thanks this would work too and I agree. I found the issue. So I have an annimation-wrapper over the button so when I click it clicks that and not the button. So, now I need to find how to target the button instead of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I have code that is very similar to yours, and it works fine. The only difference is that this is how my handleClick looks:

```
handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({

          displayMap: true,
          isOpened: !this.state.isOpened,
          searchTerm: this.state.value
          });
        console.log("The link was clicked.");
      }
```

So, you may just need to change your code to:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
  };
```